# horizontal image rows with variable height

Tags: html, css, grid, gallery

I want to make a justified image gallery with fixed width images of variable height. 
Unfortunately I can only find justified galleries with fixed heights.

When fixing the width instead of the height, white-space appears between the images vertically.

current situation: http://redbird.driesbos.com/justified.html

should become: http://www.redbird.driesbos.com/Capture1.jpg

HTML

```
<section id="justified">  
    <a href="project-page1.html">
        <img src="img/justified1.jpg"/>
    </a>
    <a href="project-page2.html">
        <img src="img/justified2.jpg"/>
    </a>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#justified {
    padding: 30px;
    width: 95vw;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

 #justified img {
    height: auto;
    width: 420px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: middle;
}
```

Comment: What it is you are trying to do? are you trying to have all your images look the same shape and size on the screen?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I'd like to have the gallery like this http://www.redbird.driesbos.com/Capture1.jpg - meaning that the images in justified gallery have fixed width and variable height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Isotope for that !

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: That's a great looking plugin! Will fiddle around with it and report if it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change both width and height to 100% so that all the images will have same width and height.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set your `a` to `display:inline-block; float:left` - it will kill whitespaces
2. Via javascript detect width of the links and set the same height:

   ```
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
       var el = document.querySelectorAll('.someClass')

       function setElHeight() {

           var elWidth = el[0].offsetWidth;
           for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
               el[i].style["height"] = (elHeight + 'px');
           }
       }
       setElHeight();
   });
   ```

I use this concept on my [blog](http://johnnyssolution.com/)

Comment: Hi Johnny. Thanks for the suggestion. I do however want variable height and only the width fixed. So even with display: inline; and float: left; there is whitespace between images vertically.

Comment: Sorry...Now i've understood what you are trying to do... My method isn't appropriate for your situation :(